# Android Camera pick image and upload

Tags: android

I have written code to capture photo and upload the captured image to the Facebook.It worked great for all the devices but when i try to run the app on Samsung galaxy s3,the app got crashed and given outofmemory error and when i compressed the image it showing Null-pointer exception.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
         this.file = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "tmp_"
                        + String.valueOf(System
                                .currentTimeMillis())
                        + ".jpg");
        ImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        try {
            intent.putExtra(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    ImageCaptureUri);
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

            startActivityForResult(intent,
                    PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
```

### }

::onActivityResult

```
uploadBitmap= decodeFile(MainActivity.this.file);



                         int width = uploadBitmap.getWidth()/3;
                         int height = uploadBitmap.getHeight()/3;


                 //     uploadBitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(uploadBitmap, 50, 50, false);

                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        uploadBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);





                        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                        // Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);

                        if (photoUrl != null) {
                            Bundle params = new Bundle();

                            params.putByteArray("photo", byteArray);

                            params.putString("caption",
                                    MainActivity.locationData+" lat: "+MainActivity.latitude+" long:"+MainActivity.longitude);

                            String place ="\"location\""+": {"+
                                   "\"latitude\""+":"+"\"12.9833\""+","+
                                   "\"longitude\""+":"+"\"77.5833\""+
                                "}";


                            params.putString("place", placeid);

                            Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST",
                                    new PhotoUploadListener(), null);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error capturing image",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to decode as below

```
public static Bitmap decodeFile(File f,int WIDTH,int HIGHT){
        try {
            //Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_WIDTH=WIDTH;
            final int REQUIRED_HIGHT=HIGHT;
            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale=1;
            while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_WIDTH && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_HIGHT)
                scale*=2;

            //Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for giving suggestion i have already decoded before the line int width = uploadBitmap.getWidth()/3; int height=uploadBitmap.getHeight()/3; But i am trying to know why it crashes on samsung s3 while working on other devices.

Comment: by using this function inSampleSize depends on a width and height you pass..  i also had same problem to get high resolution image from gallery and camera from galaxy note. now solved.. so your problem is i think to get high resolution image

Comment: thanks what height and width u passed for galaxy note for this method?

Comment: im using this method with 400,400 it worked fine with s3.But it getting hanged when uploading from samsung Note(ICS).But if i test the same app with Samsung Note with 2.3  with external storage it worked

Comment: reduce width and height and try again .. if u satisfy with my answer than accept plz..

Comment: it gives me /storage/emulated/0/tmp_1456580445499.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) exception while trying to call decodeFile method at this line BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o); Can you explain why i am facing with this issue?